# How to write data from a genetic evolutionary algorithm to an external file in python

Tags: python

I wrote a genetic algorithm in order to find the best fiber layout in a carbon fiber reinforced polymer composite brake booster. Both finite element model and the optimization algorithm were written in Python. 
I am trying to print every information regarding the optimization, but I did not find a way so far.
Could someone assist me on how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

regards,
Humb.

Comment: `print("carbon fiber reinforced polymer composite brake booster")`

Comment: this is not a question ! If you want help, publish some code, show what you tried! this question should be close soon

Comment: You need to be clearer, what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

As it was not clear from your question what data where you taking about, is it the results or some fine tuned parameters as in neural networks?

So a more Generic answer is :
You can always dump all the parameters and data form genetic algorithm to a pickle file.

```
import cPickle as pickle
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(Whatever_parameters_in_whichever_data_structure, f)
```

and then you can load the file again when you need that data

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
  Whatever_parameters_in_whichever_data_structure = pickle.load(f)
```

also you can separately dump and load different lists and dictonaries into a single pickle file ([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641493/how-to-cpickle-dump-and-load-separate-dictionaries-to-the-same-file))

Cheers!