# Writting in file with cpickle

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a numppy array with 170*3072 size as DATA.and have a list with 170 member as LABELS.I made a dictionary like below:

```
Dict={"DATA":Train_data,"LABELS":Labels}
```

I want to write the dictionary in a file with cpickle.how can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

cpickle or pickle has dump() api/method - which can take an outputstream, as  [described here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch08s03.html)

[Check out the answer at this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641516/14805380)

[Few more examples over here](https://pymotw.com/3/pickle/index.html)

[Python pickle docs..](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: please, can you edit your answer adding more details? Once you'll have more reputation you'll be able to comment under every post, suggesting useful links. But when you answer you must explain the best you can how you arrived to that specific conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pickle

Dict={"DATA":Train_data,"LABELS":Labels}

with open('dump_dictionary.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(Dict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```